# Questions about a possible way of representing construcive ordinal numbers

Tags: set-theory

Let $K$ be the set of all total recursive functions of non-negative integers having only non-negative integers as values. Let $L$ be any well-ordered subset of $K$ in which the ordering $<$ is defined as follows. If $f(n),g(n)$ are elements of $L$, then $f(n)< g(n)$ just in case there exists a non-negative integer $h$ such that $f(n)$ is less than $g(n)$ whenever n is greater than $h$. Suppose that $L$ contains a maximum element. Is the ordinal number of the well-ordered set $L$ always a constructive ordinal number (in the sense of Church and Kleene)? Can arbitrarily large constructive ordinal numbers be represented in this way?

Comment: I seem to have lost most of my question

Comment: Please disregard this last comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the first question is No and the second question Yes, because in fact every countable (successor) ordinal arises that way. (The successor part is only because you insisted that $L$ has a maximal element; otherwise we could say that every countable ordinal arises this way.)

The reason is that $K$ contains a countable dense linear order, and every countable linear order, including every countable well-order, can therefore be found as a suborder.

In particular, we can find $L$ having order type larger than $\omega^{CK}_1$ this way.

Comment: I was trying to work out whether any useful notation systems for a segment of the countable ordinal numbers could be developed, using recursive functions-or even just primitive recursive functions-as the notations. When you pointed out the existence of subsets of K which are densely ordered by "<", I saw what was wrong with this idea and why Hardy (who, I believe, first investigated the ordering "<") never went very far with it.